# why I can't connect using VPN to my office with some ISPs?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, isp

I have a VPN connection to connect from home to my office, I can connect to my work network correctly from home, but I can't  connect in other places (other ISPs)
what's the problem? dose ISP block some port or something like that?

Comment: possibly. You should be less vague. Which ISPs do you have problems with? What type of VPN is it? What sort of error do you get when you try to connect and it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very little ISP's will block VPN's - because there is no reason to (with connecting in China, you might have an issue). Generally there are three types of VPN's. All but one has fallback ports incase of ISP blocking. I will guess you are using L2TP/IPSec because of the encryption and reliability in a corporate environment, this VPN type has fall back ports.

With this types of VPN, certain group policies will prevent you from connecting within certain networks.

For example, when using L2TP/IPSec you will not be able to connect (by default) from within a tier 3 network. Simplify if you're behind a local network NAT which is behind an ISP NAT. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) This is not the ISP, but rather a security setting enforced by your Office's IT on a certin network.

For a general fix: (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926179)

I recommend asking your IT about this issue - to find a permanent fix.

Comment: NAT-T is used in the case where you need to do NAT Traversal. If your endpoints support it, you should be able to get through.